# Discrete arithmetic subgroup

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic, geometric-topology

Let $F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ for some $d>0$ be a real quadratic field and $G=\rm{GL}_2$, say over $\mathbb{Z}$. For any embedding $F\hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, the group $G(\mathcal{O}_d)$ is not discrete in $G(\mathbb{R})$. But for the pair of the two embeddings of $F$ into $\mathbb{R}$, the group $G(\mathcal{O}_d)$ becomes discrete in $G(\mathbb{R})\times G(\mathbb{R})$. This is confusing me. Is $G(\mathcal{O}_d)$ now a discrete group in its own or not? Why is it discrete in one group, but not in the other. Are there different topologies or what is the matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to know the notion of [induced topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_topology).

*A priori*, there is no topology on the set $G(\mathcal O_d)$. But we have two embeddings $\iota_{1, 2}: G(\mathcal O_d) \hookrightarrow G(\Bbb R)$, given by the two real embeddings of $F$ into $\Bbb R$. They together give another embedding $\iota: G(\mathcal O_d) \hookrightarrow G(\Bbb R) \times G(\Bbb R)$ such that $\iota(x) = (\iota_1(x), \iota_2(x))$.

On the other hand, we have canonical topologies on $\Bbb G(\Bbb R)$ and on $G(\Bbb R) \times G(\Bbb R)$ (product topology). The three embeddings $\iota_1, \iota_2, \iota$ then induce three different topologies on $G(\mathcal O_d)$.

It turns out that, under the first two induced topologies, $G(\mathcal O_d)$ is not discrete; but under the third induced topology (via $\iota$), $G(\mathcal O_d)$ is discrete.

Is that clear now?

Comment: Oh I see. Yes, it is clear now. Thank you very much !